# React Native Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._root.setNativeProps')

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create custom button. For this, I wrapped my existed view into **TouchableHighlight** (write me please another way, if it's not suitable here)

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.freeTimeTapped} underlayColor="white">
    <LabelsView data={this.freeTimeData} 
                containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3A65FF' }} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

This code throws an error **touchable child must either be native**, described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1040), for example. So, I added

```
setNativeProps = (nativeProps) => {
    this._root.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
}
```

error disappeared, but now I receive an error

> React Native Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this._root.setNativeProps')

after touch. What am I doing wrong?

More code about LabelsView:

```
export default class LabelsView extends Component {
    // Make TouchableHighlight wrapper work
    setNativeProps = (nativeProps) => {
        this._root.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle]}>
                <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                    <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.leftText} </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <Text style={[styles.durationText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightTopText + ' hrs'} </Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.rangeText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightBottomText} </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you doing in "LabelsView" ? Please show the code for it ?

Comment: @AkshayRao, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the same sitaution as yours and found that the only thing you are doing wrong is you are wrapping a class inside the **TouchableHighlight** . If you want to wrap it in any touchable component then react native needs the native child, So to resolves this change your code as follows:-

```
<LabelsView freeTimeTapped={this.freeTimeTapped} data={this.freeTimeData} 
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3A65FF' }} />
```

and your LabelsView class as follows:-

```
    render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.freeTimeTapped} underlayColor="white">
        <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle]}>
            <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.leftText} </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                <Text style={[styles.durationText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightTopText + ' hrs'} </Text>
                <Text style={[styles.rangeText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightBottomText} </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
```

If you still hava any problem then let me know :)

In case you want to have it in parent, just fix your code to this:

```
export default class LabelsView extends Component {
    // Make TouchableHighlight wrapper work
    setNativeProps = (nativeProps) => {
        this._root.setNativeProps(nativeProps);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View ref={component => this._root = component} style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle]}>
                <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                    <Text style={[styles.nameText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.leftText} </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <Text style={[styles.durationText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightTopText + ' hrs'} </Text>
                    <Text style={[styles.rangeText, styles.textColor]}> {this.props.data.rightBottomText} </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

You missed **ref={component => this._root = component}**

Comment: yes, it's nice workaround. however, I wander how to actually do wrapper inside parent. with your code every LavelsView instance will have touch, which I don't want